# Need to put a variable inside jquery each

Tags: jquery, each

I have a function like this

```
var json = "location.cities"; 

$(<--here-->).each(function() {
 .....
});
```

so

I need to put the variable " json " inside the brackets and fire the function. So is there anyway to do that? please anyone help me regarding this ? I am really stucked here.

Comment: Quite simple: `$(json)`

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you even try ? Cause from where I see it first comment (and first answer) are right...

Comment: @Bartdude They're right if he has some `<location>` elements in his DOM that have the class `cities` on them, but that seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: Anthony, exactly. All I understood from his explanation is that he doesn't know how to add a variable in there. But if he wants to loop through each city in the location variable, just calling `$(location.cities)` would suffice aswel, no need to store a variable in a variable if you don't plan on doing anything with it.

Comment: @StefanCandan If `location.cities` is a variable containing a collection, then `$(location.cities)` isn't correct to iterate over it; they'd want `$.each(location.cities, function(i, val) {...});` instead. If `json` really is a string then it becomes slightly more complicated (the name also makes no sense).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You're right, but we're just guessing here. If the poster would supply more information about how location.cities is filled, we'd be able to put out an answer that suits to his needs.

Comment: @StefanCandan it's not working. But thanks a lot for your answer. Samba 's answer worked for me.

Comment: @Paul Creasey thank very much guys, I am really appreciate your answers. Again thanks a lot for coming to help. Samba's answer worked in my case.

Comment: @Bartdude thank very much guys, I am really appreciate your answers. Again thanks a lot for coming to help. Samba's answer worked in my case.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thank very much guys, I am really appreciate your answers. Again thanks a lot for coming to help. Samba's answer worked in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following one

You kept like `"location.cities"`  .It becomes string now

```
$(location.cities).each(function() { ..... });
```

or

var json = location.cities;

```
$(json).each(function() {
  .....
 });
```

Comment: Your second answer worked for me.I really needed to do it in that way.I have used double quotes when I was declaring the variable. That was my fault. you really saved my time. I owe you beer dude. Thanks a lot.